# Firebase with Swift ambiguous use of observeEventType

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been pulling my hair out because of this. Going to all the pages with related incidents and multiple tutorials I find nothing wrong with my code here, but somehow it only doesn't fail if I print out the values (which works) or assign them as! NSArray which then gives me an empty array.

a print of snapshot.value shows

```
( friend1, 
  friend2, 
  friend3 
)
```

I've tried snapshot.value.values ... no dice.
I've tried playing with the unwrapping ... no dice.
and this is my final attempt:

```
    friendsList = [String]()

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot) -> Void in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {

        } else {
            for child in snapshot {
                self.friendsList.append(child.value)
            }
        }
    }
```

which gives me the ambiguous thing again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just some coding errors

Remove:  (snapshot)-> Void

Change: **child in snapshot** as snapshot is not a sequence, whereas snapshot.children is

I assume you want to store the friends name as a string and *name* is a key in your structure. So change **self.friendsList.append(child.value**) to

```
let name = child.value["name"] as? String
friendsList.append(name!)
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
var friendsList = [String]()

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    if snapshot.value is NSNull {

    } else {
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let name = child.value["name"] as? String
            friendsList.append(name!)
        }
        print("\(friendsList)")
    }
})
```

Comment: Well the keys in the structure are 0, 1, 2, ... as per default when you setValue as an array. Each child then has a unique key and I want to loop through all the values. How can I do that?

Comment: While Firebase does have support for Array's, they are generally not recommended as there are other, better ways for your structure (leveraging the uid or childByAutoId are winners). Their use is very situational and get you easily coded into corner. The 0,1, 2 are keys so you can iterate over those or even put them directly into an Array and iterate over that. But, as I mentioned you should look into other structures. If you have a question about working with array's post that separately. If my answer helped, please accept it!

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually didn't work. I'll tell you what did, though. I printed the snapshot.value!.dynamicType to know the type which when unwrapped from AnyObject becomes an NSArray. I then downcasted as! [String] which then worked. I really appreciate you taking the time to help :)

Comment: The code in the answer does in fact work and answered the question about the error you were getting. It sounds like you are going through a lot of unneeded gyrations to get your code working. In this case, the simpler the better as it will be more maintainable long term. I again encourage you to not use arrays as numeric keys in a JSON structure are a pain.

Comment: Well other than numeric structures how would you change this: { friends: {0: user1, 1: user2, 2: user3}}?

Comment: @Aylii There's a 100 different ways but here are two:   friends/uid_0: true, friends/uid_1: true. friends/uid_2:true. If you need to store more data then that, create nodes inside the friends node with childByAutoId and you could then store all kinds of stuff within each child node:  friends/auto_id_0/ then you could have lots of children like uid: the uid,  name: persons name,  lastContacted:  some timestamp. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    })
```

Work for me, Xcode 8.3.2