# Ambigious use of 'Key'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to print the Key name of a piece of data from Firebase using swift but I keep getting 'Ambigious use of Key' when I type something like:

```
for child in snapshot.children{
    print(child.key)
}
```

How can I avoid this? All help is appreciated very much!

Comment: Is `child.key` a `String`?

Comment: yes, it is a String representation of the Key part of the data piece

Comment: You want to print the `name` received from firebase right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245272/firebase-with-swift-ambiguous-use-of-observeeventtype

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that question does not answer my question unfortunately

Comment: They are asking different things

Comment: and yes @Dershowitz123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it as `FIRDataSnapshot`. Try doing this:

```
for child in snapshot.children{
 let child1 = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        print(child1.key)
}
```

Comment: Anytime. :) Happy coding!