# Firebase autocomplete API's cause compiler error Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The top line of code is the suggested autocomplete provided by Xcode, which doesn't compile. The bottom piece of code has been modified with code provided here 
[Firebase with Swift ambiguous use of observeEventType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245272/firebase-with-swift-ambiguous-use-of-observeeventtype)

Everytime I type this code out i have to modify it, which is tedious. Why is the autocomplete wrong? It is not just for this `.observe`, but all of them.

[image]

Comment: When I type *rootRef.child("asd").child("asa").observe* Xcode pops up a list of autocomplete options - none of which are observe(.value). Xcode 8.1 Swift 3. Have you tried cleaning the project or perhaps create a new project just to test the autocomplete to see if it's specific to that app?

Comment: Hi Jay, I had selected the .observe(eventType: FIRDataEventType, with: (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void)  option, then just filled in the placeholders with .value and snapshot, respectively.

Comment: Ah. I see. So yes, when I type the .observe part, then press Tab, the whole whole first parameter is highlighted *eventType: FIRDataEventType* so if you start typing at that point, it replaces that text. What is should do is just replace the FIRDataEventType and leave the eventType: portion alone. This issue is duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your Firebase framework is not the latest version?(as the latest one is now supporting the Swift 3 syntax). 
Try `pod update`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and updated all my podfiles and unfortunately i still have the same problem. So does your Xcode autocomplete to the bottom piece of code?

Comment: Same thing happens to me, very annoying.